# how to upload image file to mysqldb through ajax request in django without using directly form data

Tags: python, ajax, django

i want to store the path of the image in one of my folders when i upload an image and i want to retrive it from that can anyone help me

my code is :

html page:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="button" class="button" value="ADD HOTEL" onclick="addnewhotel()">
</form>
```

js file:

```
function addnewhotel() {
    var image=$('#imagefile').val();
    ajaxsetup();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/add_hotel',
        data:{'image':image},
        success:function (data) {
            $('#hotel_result').html(data);

        }
    })

}
```

veiws.py:

```
def add_hotel(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image=request.FILES.get('image')
        Hotel(image=image).save()
            return HttpResponse('ADDED')
```

models.py:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="/media")
```

Comment: it is indeed the path of the file that should go into the db and not the file

Comment: k then how can i retrive the image file of that path

Comment: If that is your question, please edit the question to reflect that but without invalidating the answers you have already got